# Is it possible to get the same cross validation score for many classification model

Tags: select, classification, random-forest, decision-tree, cross-validation

I have 5 column of dummy representing 5 categories. I run 3 classification model but got the same mean value of cross validation score. I wonder if this could be possible?

My code is below,

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=1/3, random_state=88888)

cvL = cross_val_score(LogisticRegression(), x_test, y_test,cv=5)

cvD = cross_val_score(DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5), x_test, y_test,cv=5)

cvF = cross_val_score(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10), x_test, y_test,cv=5)

I get the same score for all 3 model, which is

array([0.78125   , 0.78125   , 0.77777778, 0.77777778, 0.77777778])
```

My questions are:

1. Is this outcome possible? If so, how do I know which model to choose?
2. When I change random state in test_train_split, i could sometime get different score for different model but this rarely happen and I do not know which random state I should choose.
3. Why do I get same score for sampling 3th to 5th which is 0.7777777778

Comment: Try adding a numerical variable in the models (can be made up), see if the scores stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it is possible for two different classifiers to give you the same score. The likelihood of this vastly changes from problem to problem. My first instinct was to question the size of your data. Too small and it would be easy to overfit and learn only a subset of the data.
2. Normally, you don't need to specify the random state. Reserve this for when you want to be able to reproduce results on each run given the same data and classifier. You shouldn't have to pick the best random state.
3. It doesn't look like you actually are training the data. You jump straight to scoring the test set. I recommend you go back to the sklearn documentation and read a few more tutorials, but basically you'd want something like:

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=1/3, random_state=88888)

```
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(x_train, y_train)

cvL = cross_val_score(logreg, x_test, y_test, cv=5)
```

Of course, one major feature of cross validation is the ability to pick the best hyperparameters. I recommend finding a tutorial on sklearn's `GridSearchCV`. For every classifier, there are parameters of the underlying model which you can tune to achieve the best classification performance. This class helps you find those.

Answer (score 0):

Use the training set `x_train` to see if the scores change for the different models. No point in using the `x_test` for running cross-validation as training set would have more rows to train the estimators.

Also, don't change the `random_state` for `train_test_split` as that is just used to reproduce the same split for training and test.